# mySQL database search exact phrase

Tags: database, wordpress, search

what is the easiest way on a wordpress site to have a database of unique ID numbers and have a search field that searches the exact phrase and displays results?

Answer (score 1):

create a table to have unique ids, and words

To search by a word
then use -> `SELECT * FROM words_table WHERE word LIKE "%ed%";`
This will return results where ed is in words such as end**ed**, start**ed**, startl**ed**, **ed**ucation

To search by an id
use -> `SELECT * FROM words_table WHERE id = {$id}`

Comment: so honestly though how can I accomplish this? I have a specific search template for my "ID search" area and it works, its just returning every related spelling etc

Comment: Maybe I can just have search 'taxonomies' - basically what I have is I created a "Valid Members" Post type, and that post type has an attribute or taxonomy called "ID" I just want to search those ID's (that are hidden,ofcourse) and display the ID number, the Expiration date, and the Date of Birth

Comment: How would you like to search those ids, using what parameters, such as age, sex, etc.

Comment: well it would just be the body of the posts I guess. "ID Number" is the only thing I want to search, the other info is just attached to it

Comment: Ok How can I modify the wordpress search query to only return exact phrase

Comment: to return exact phrase you need => SELECT * FROM words_table WHERE word = "word_to_search";